# Resize Hair Particles with Emitter - 2.8

Tags: particles, hair

I've built a city scene using hair particle systems to populate it with buildings. Those systems are reused multiple times through the scene. Due a series of requirements I need to be able to rotate and scale those systems independently of each other. I had a partial success by doing that to their emitters. Rotating works, scaling doesn't.

**Hence the question: How can you make hair particles scale with their emitters?**

#### Things that don't work

- Scaling the emitter
- Parenting the emitter to another mesh/an empty and scaling this parent. The hair system scales, but only temporarily. As soon you cause a desgraph update for the emitters by hitting tab, reloading the file or rendering it the hair reverts to its original scale
- The hair systems are shared between multiple emitters for performance reasons, so:

  - Changing the hair length affects all of them at once
  - Changing the collection/object scale that replaces the hair strand (*Particle System > Render* tab) also affects all of them
  - Changing the scale of the original meshes replacing hair strands affects all systems using them
  - Using a *Length Vertex Group* to control it in each emitter kinda works. You can't scale (hair) buildings up though and it's harder to set exact values and maintain them. It also causes the hair to switch between scaled/unscaled states in some cases as if you had a circular dependency issue; but there's nothing in the Console.
  - Using the length brush in the *Particle Edit* mode works to scale up and down, but it's also a nightmare to maintain

Ideas?